# ReactJS Nested Lists (flux)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs, reactjs-flux

I'm messing around with React and am having an issue with nesting lists.  I have 2 lists - projects & todos, each todo has a `project_id` on it.  I have 4 components related to these lists: `projects-component` which renders a list of `project-component`s, each having its own `todos-component` with a `projectId` property set to the project's ID.  The `todos-component` uses a `TodosWatchMixin` passing a `getTodos` function that relies on `component.props.projectId` to get the list of todos, which then renders a list of the 4th component: `todo-component` (not shown here.)  It all works wonderfully until I add a new project to the list.  The project shows up, but the todo items shift - the new project has the todos of another project in it, and most of the rest of the project's todos seem to shift as well... Interacting (refreshing or checking off a todo in the wrong project) fixes it - so I'm guessing somehow my  Using the React Chrome Dev Tool I can see the new project has it's own ID on it, but it also has a the list of items... What am I missing?

Here's some code snippets:

**projects-component.js**

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */

var React = require('react');
var Project = require('./project-component');
var ProjectsWatchMixin = require('./projects-watch-mixin');
var ProjectStore = require('./projects-store');
var Actions = require('./project-actions');
var MasonryMixin = require('./masonry-mixin.js');
var masonryOptions = {
    transitionDuration: 0,
    itemSelector: '.project-wrap'
};


function getProjects() {
  return {projects:ProjectStore.getProjects()};
}

var Projects = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'ProjectComponent',
  mixins: [ProjectsWatchMixin(getProjects), MasonryMixin(masonryOptions)],
  loadDemoData: function() {
    Actions.loadDemoData();
  },
  submitNewProject: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = this.refs.title.getDOMNode();
    if (t.value == '') return t.focus()
    Actions.addProject({title:t.value})
  },
  render: function() {
    var projectList = this.state.projects.map(function(project, i){
      return (
        <div className="project-wrap" key={i}>
          <Project model={project} />
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div ref="masonryContainer" className="projects">
        <div className="project-wrap text-center">
          <div className="project">
            <header>
              <h3>New Project</h3>
            </header>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitNewProject} className="input-group">
              <input type="text" className="frm-ctrl" ref="title" />
              <span className="input-group-addon">
                <button type="submit" className="btn"><i className="fa fa-plus-circle" /></button>
              </span>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          {projectList}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

});


module.exports = Projects;
```

**project-component.js**

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */

var React = require('react');
var Todos = require('../todos/todos-component');

var Project = React.createClass({
  noop: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // yeah, yeah... not exactly noop!
  },
  render: function() {
    var m = this.props.model;
    var st = m.get('subTitle');
    if (st) st = <small>{st}</small> 
    return (
      <div className="project">
        <header>
          <h3>{m.get('title')} {st}</h3>
        </header>
        <p>{m.get('description')}</p>
        <Todos projectId={m.get('id')} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Project;
```

**todos-component.js**

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */

var React = require('react');
var Todo = require('./todo-component');
var TodosWatchMixin = require('./todos-watch-mixin');
var TodoStore = require('./todos-store');
// var TodoActions = require('./todo-actions');

function getTodos(component) {
  return {todos:TodoStore.getTodos(component.props.projectId)};
}

var TodoList = React.createClass({
  mixins: [TodosWatchMixin(getTodos)],

  render: function() {
    var todoList = this.state.todos.map(function(t,i){
      return <Todo key={i} model={t} />
    });
    return (
      <ul className="todo-list">
        {todoList}
      </ul>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = TodoList;
```

**projects-store.js**

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var LocalStorage = require('backbone.localstorage');

var Dispatcher = require('./project-dispatcher');
var Constants = require('./project-constants');
// var Actions = require('../actions/app-actions');
var merge = require('react/lib/merge');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var TodoStore = require('../todos/todos-store');
var CHANGE_EVENT = "change";
if (window) window.Backbone = Backbone;

var Project = Backbone.Model.extend({
  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("com.thomporter.todosApp.projects"),
  defaults: {
    sort_order: 0,
    title: '',
    subTitle: '',
    description: ''
  }
});

var Projects = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Project,
  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("com.thomporter.todosApp.projects"),
  initialize: function(){
    this.comparator = this.comparatorDefault;
    this.sort();
  },
  comparatorDefault: function (model) {
    return model.get('sort_order');
  }
});

var _projects = new Projects();

_projects.fetch();

var _demoDataLoaded = false;
function _loadDemoData () {
  if (_demoDataLoaded) return;
  _demoDataLoaded = true;
  demo = require('./demo-data');
  demo.projects.map(function(p, i){
    var todos = p.todos
    delete p.todos;
    p.id = i+1000;
    ProjectStore.addProject(p);
    if (todos) {
      todos.map(function(t){
        t.project_id = p.id;
        TodoStore.addTodo(t);

      });
    }
    // _projects.sync();

  });
};
function _addProject (project) {
  if (!project.id) {
    project.id = (new Date()).getTime();
  }
  var p = new Project(project);
  p.save(project, {success:function(){
    _projects.add(p);
    ProjectStore.emitChange();
  }});
};

function _removeProject () {
  alert('Not Implemented Yet.');
};

var ProjectStore = merge(EventEmitter.prototype, {
   emitChange:function(){
    this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT)
  },
  addChangeListener:function(callback){
    this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback)
  },

  removeChangeListener:function(callback){
    this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback)
  },

  get: function(id) {
    return _projects.get(id);
  },

  getProjects: function() {
    return _projects;
  },

  addProject: function(project) {
    _addProject(project);

  },

  dipatcherIndex: Dispatcher.register(function(payload){
    var action = payload.action;
    switch(payload.action.actionType) {
      case Constants.ADD_PROJECT:
        _addProject(payload.action.project);
        return; // will emit change after save success
      case Constants.REMOVE_PROJECT:
        _removeProject(payload.action.project);
        break;
      case Constants.LOAD_DEMO_DATA:
        _loadDemoData();
        break;
    }
    ProjectStore.emitChange();
    return true;
  }),

});
// _loadDemoData();
module.exports = ProjectStore;

if (window) window._projects = _projects;
```

You can see [the work in progress here](http://react-todos.thomporter.com/).  Hit `ctrl+shift+L` or `command+shift+L` to load the test data, then add a new project and you'll probably see the Farm List items show up in your new project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the index of your `Array.map` call as your component key. This means that your list components aren't guaranteed to have the same key values on each render. React uses these internally to reconcile against the DOM when doing a diff, so things will render differently each time if you use an array index as the key. It's explicitly mentioned in the docs: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children.

You need to assign your keys based on the natural ids of your items (i.e., not an array index) and also ensure they are strings (from the link above):

> Numeric properties will be ordered sequentially and before other
>   properties. If this happens React will render components out of order.
>   This can be avoided by adding a string prefix to the key

Comment: This was it.  I had actually tried this and didn't think it worked, but I was setting the project keys to `'k' + i`, instead of `'k' + project.get('id')`.  Your answer made me go back to look and notice this, thanks! =)